# How do I change the background color of the twitter bootstrap drop-down menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok , so I tried to change the background color of the opened twitter bootstrap drop down menu to a dark grey but it is still white ! HELP would be so much appreciated...

Here is the CSS code :

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color:#606060;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="span2">
  <div id="networkSelection">
    <label class="play-label"><div class="localized-label">NETWORK</div></label>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Select Network <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Los Angeles Unified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Harry Potter Club</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">X-Games Enthusiasts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pasadena Kids Club</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">RECOMMENDED NETWORKS</a>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Los Angeles Unified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Harry Potter Club</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">X-Games Enthusiasts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pasadena Kids Club</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you put the CSS **after** bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to [work](http://jsbin.com/ecogaz/1). You can customize Bootstrap on [**this page**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html). There is a section for dropdowns. Set whatever colors you want and download the new CSS.

Comment: what do you mean ?  I just need to be able to change the color of my dropdown menu to a dark grey but it is not working at all .. can you please show me how I can do it . At first glance , it is self explanatory , I just did  background-color:#606060; but it is still showing white !!

Comment: I got what you meant , but when I download the css , it produces an error and I dont get any CSS file

Comment: It'll give you a whole new bootstrap css file. You replace your existing bootstrap with the new one. Look at the first link in my answer, it shows it working. Your need to put that custom CSS **after** all other bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Also you only need the styles you change, not everything. You should only need the background color line.